# What will the best solution for this multiple optional filter?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

These are all optional fields, so will I have to write multiple queries with conditions or is there any way to handle this using Laravel? What will be the query looks like?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: See this Laracasts episode: [Let's Build A Forum with Laravel and TDD - A Lesson in Refactoring](https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/15)

Comment: https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable

Comment: @RossWilson thanks for recommending a package of mine, to be precise OP would have to use [custom filters](https://github.com/Kyslik/laravel-filterable#custom-filters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a bit on how the filters are submitted, but you can do one of the following two things (and probably a gazillion more...):

```
public function listCars(Request $request)
{
    $cars = Car::when($request->get('make'), function ($query, $make) {
            $query->where('make', $make);
        })
        ->when($request->get('model'), function ($query, $model) {
            $query->where('model', $model);
        })
        ->...
        ->get();

    // do what you have to do
}
```

So you are basically wrapping your query builder calls in `when($value, $callback)`, which will only execute `$callback` if `$value` evaluates to true. When you retrieve a not set parameter with `$request->get('parameter')`, it will return null and the callback is not executed. But be careful, if `$value` is `0` it will also not execute the callback. So be sure you don't have this as an index.

As alternative to this, you can also do the same thing but with a bit less eloquent expressions...

```
public function listCars(Request $request)
{
    $query = Car::query();

    if($request->filled('make')) {
        $query->where('make', $request->get('make'));
    }
    if($request->filled('model')) {
        $query->where('model', $request->get('model'));
    }

    // some more filtering, sorting, ... here

    $cars = $query->get();

    // do what you have to do
}
```

Comment: This is working but here the year, engine is in relational table "Models" e:g I can all the years and engine by $vehicel->models[0]->engine, $vehicel->models[1]->engine. 
if i pass direct year or engine it gives me Column not found error

Comment: Your description doesn't really make any sense, but it also sounds like it is not related to this question. You asked for a good way to design the filtering, not how to code the filters themselves. Maybe open a new question for the filters itself with a detailed description of your tables, relations, etc.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! I had just a little bit different situation but your answer helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of something similar query i have in my app.

```
   $filters = $vehicle->newQuery();

    if (!empty($request->make)) {
        $filters->where('make_id', $request->make);

    }
    if (!empty($request->carmodel)) {
        $filters->where('carmodel_di', $request->carmodel);

    }
    if (!empty($request->year)) {
        $filters->where('year_id', $request->year);

    }
    if (!empty($request->engine)) {
        $filters->where('engine_id', $request->engine);

    }

    if (!empty($request->price)) {
        $filters->where('price_id', $request->price);

    }

    $cars = $filters->latest()->paginate(50);
```

and now push the **$cars** variable to view. I hope this works for you or atleast gives you an idea on how to proceed

Comment: your code is working but Namoshek and akramwasim method are perfect if you are using Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple way, you can also make the joins conditional inside the `->when()` condition, if you are in Laravel version > 5.4, use `$request>filled()` instead of `$request->has()`

```
    public function listCars(Request $request)
{
    $cars = Car::when($request->has('make'), function ($query)use($request) {
            $query->join('maker','car.makerId','=','maker.id')
            ->where('make', $request->input('make'));
        })
        ->when($request->has('model'), function ($query)use($request) {
            $query->where('model', $request->input('model'));
        })
        ->...
        ->get();

    // you can even make the join conditionaly, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fiterItem = ['make','model','year','engine','price'];
$filters = $vehicle->newQuery();

foreach ($filter as $item) {
    if ($r->filled($item)) {
      $list->where($item, $r->query($item));
    }
}
$list = $filters->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?