# Starting Query Builder without using a query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So, I can use `User::where('username', '!=', null)->get()`;

However, I am in a case where I want to chain queries using if conditions starting from the first one, and `where('username', '!=', null)` is unnecessary in this case. Let me give a pseudo example:

I am running a report based on Users where there are several fields. I want to initialize the query builder like this, and chain queries using if statements.

```
$user = User::class();   // I know I can't use this line, however you'll get the idea.

if (isset($gender)) {
   $user = $user->where('gender', $gender);
}

if (isset($age)) {
   $user = $user->where('age', $age);
}

$users = $user->get()
```

Is the only way starting the query (in the first line) with:

```
$user = User::where('username', '!=', null)
```

Comment: Just today I answered a question where the answer fits your question perfectly. Feel free to [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394497/what-will-the-best-solution-for-this-multiple-optional-filter/51394695#51394695).

Comment: By the way, it is better to use `$query->whereNotNull('username')` instead of `$query->where('username', '!=', null)` as it will leverage the native grammar of your SQL connection (i.e. it is more portable across DB systems).

Comment: @Namoshek Aaaha! That's interesting! Does the when works like `isset()`, what if I don't have `$request->dummy` in my request and I use it in `when()` like `when($request->dummy..`

Comment: Please have a look at the code of `when($value, $callback, $default)` [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L88-L97). It basically only performs `if($value)`, so using it on `request()->get('field')` is ok, but may fail to work if you have for example an input of `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instantiate your object like :

```
$user = (new User);
```

**NOTE:** However it will be better to use `when()` instead of the if statements.

```
$users = User::when($gender, function ($query, $gender) {
    $query->where('gender', $gender);
})
->when($age, function ($query, $age) {
    $query->where('age', $age);
})
->get();
```

If the variables are not initialized you could use `isset()` method like :

```
$users = User::when( isset($gender), function ($query, $gender) {
    $query->where('gender', $gender);
})
->when( isset($age), function ($query, $age) {
    $query->where('age', $age);
})
->get();
```

Comment: The `when` is quite new, right? Can you please give a pseudo example?

Comment: You will need the `isset` in the `when`. So it will be `when(isset($gender), ...)`

Comment: Updated at the same time, anyway thanks for your intervention.

Comment: I've added an example @senty

Comment: You're not going to use the `when` @senty?

Comment: I can't use it because I need to check `isset()` case first. But thanks for the pro-tip! Ah, just saw the isset comment.

Comment: Glad i could help brother. But I have already added the isset check to the when

Comment: I doubt you need `isset()`. If you want to get request input in a safe manner, use `$request->input('field')` or `$request->get('field')` for example. It will return a default value you can give as second parameter, which is `null` by default.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Your change with isset will lead to wrong results. Now `$gender` in the callback function will be `true` or `false`. You'd have to use `use ($gender)` on the callback now, but this is dirty...

Comment: That depend on the version I think @Namoshek , since the isset already tested in 5.5 and 5.6 and it work just fine... And you're right, if the gender and age are recieved from a request it will be better to use `$request->get('field')` @senty.

Comment: Shouldn't depend on the version. `when($value, $callback)` passes `$value` to the `$callback` as second parameter. So if you use `isset($something)`, this can only be `true` or `false`. `git blame` says this has been since 5.4 like this.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for

```
$userQuery = User::query();
```

Then, tack on some additional clauses:

```
$userQuery->where(...);
```

Then, provide a `closure` (`->first()`, `->get()`, etc) to get your users:

```
$users = $userQuery->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the answer to OP however the other answer is pretty neat way of doing it too

Comment: No worries. The `->when()` approach makes sense here; might have to start using that method myself. Cheers!

Comment: ::query() was exactly what I was looking for. I was having trouble creating the query, because I didn't have anything to start with and I had a function that takes the query as parameter.